# How to publish an apk in AppGallery without creating a copy of app with different package

Tags: android, google-play, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, appgallery

I'm trying to publish an app on AppGallery, but when I enter my package name for new application in console project, it says that package has already been taken. The app is published on Play Store and if your search for it in AppGallery it will find it, but the AppGallery page says that the app is "not yet available". So I assume there should be a way to publish an apk in AppGallery without creating a copy of app with different package which might break all other services that I currently use. Some apps have done it already, take for instance Telegram, Shapchat, it seems that both stores point to the same app package. The question is - how to do it?

Comment: I think it is not possible to create same package twice. If this is your app you should contact customer support and claim its ownership. You will probably be asked to provide evidence for the ownership transfer.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**
The package name of an app to be released on AppGallery can be the same as on Play Store. For

> it says that package has already been taken

Please perform the following steps:

- If the application package is created in **your account**, use the created package name to enable the service. Do not create the application package repeatedly.
- If the application package has been created in **another account**, delete the package name from the corresponding account or you can [transfer the application](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/distribution/app/50112#h1-1583379969142).

App transfer services has **Common app transfer** and **Transfer of apps using the in-app purchase mode**. If your apps that have not enabled HUAWEI In-App Purchases (IAP), it is Common app transfer. Please provide your app transfer details, including the transferor account, transferee account, app name, and app ID, and qualification materials in compliance with copyright requirements based on your app type.  Send them stamped with the official seal through [this](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/support/feedback). The staff will review the application and perform the transfer. After the app is transferred, submit an app review application. The new developer's name can be displayed only after the application is approved.

- If you do not know whether your package name is repeated or not, you can query the application package name and enterprise name in the [Customer Service- Submit ticket online](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/support/feedback/#/) on the [HMS Core official website](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/).